# How do I do an ajax call to a database using Javascript, a URL and a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, key

I have been given a url of type *xxxx.xxxxx.com* as well as a key of type *FGHyehgvc787vbhj*

in order to gain read-only access to an sql database and retrieve data from it using javascript.

I have no prior experience with databases and maybe my question will sound completely stupid but I was wondering how can I combine the above information in order to get access to the database (e.g. do an ajax call and retrieve data from it..)

I'm familiar with doing ajax calls to a webpage and getting data from it using jQuery, as in :

```
$.ajax(/*url of website*/, function (data)
{
   var dataRetrieved = $(data);
   // do something with the data retrieved...
});
```

so I was wondering whether there is something equivalent to the above when it comes to making an ajax call to a database, using however a key.

Thank you for any help, and please delete this post if you find it completely pointless and excuse me in advance for that by the way.

Comment: Not enough information here to answer. You need to find some documentation that describes the API of the service you're interested.

Comment: Most likely the request you are sending to isn't a database at all, but a normal webservice that talks to a database.'

Comment: You send the AJAX call to the URL, it takes care of accessing the database. You don't have to worry about that. Just process the data it returns and put it in your web page.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually very bad design to allow client side code to interact with your database in any way.  This can be a huge security issue.  Generally you will want your server side code to do this (e.g PHP, node, etc.).  You would send a request to your server with client side code, and the server side code would do the actual work of updating the database.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a wcf service and call that service through ajax, that wont be huge security issue. 
try this

```
  $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            data: {},
            url: http:xxxxxxxxxxxx.svc/webBinding/Result?metaTag=" + meta,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success:function(result){},
            error: function(){alert(err);}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/server-side/script.php', /*url*/
    data: '', /* post data e.g name=christian&hobbie=loving */
    type: '', /* POST|GET */
    complete: function(d) {
        var data= d.responseTXT;
        /* Here you can use the data as you like */
        $('#elementid').html(data);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps...